# I'm having trouble starting an activity using class object in Android

Tags: java, android

So I'm following thenewboston's Android tutorials. I understood how to start an activity using intent. But when it comes to creating a new activity using class object the class name is not being recognized inside the Class.forname()method. But say if I created directly using Intent, it has no problem finding class. But using this, with same class path, I'm having java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`
package name- com.hello.myproject;

```
  import android.app.ListActivity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
  import android.widget.ListView;


public class Menu extends ListActivity{
    String []classes={"MainActivity","example1","example2","example3","example4","example5","example6"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        Class myclass=Class.forName("com.hello.myproject.MainActivity");//This class name is not being found, but if I copy the same path inside Intent() it has no problem and yes there is a class called MainActivity
        Intent myintent=new Intent(Menu.this,myclass );
        startActivity(myintent);
    }
}
```

Manifestfile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.hello.myproject.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Menu">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.hello.myproject.MENU" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".TextPlay">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.hello.myproject.TEXTPLAY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Why don't you just do Intent myintent = new Intent(Menu.this, MainActivity.class)?

Comment: So I can't setup an Intent based on a class variable?

Comment: @NarayanPayyoor see the answer i posted now

Answer (score 1):

Narayan Payyoor

The syntax you are using for starting Activity works only if you have added `intent-filter` inside `Activity` tag in manifest.xml file.

**For Example :**

if you are doing,

```
Class myclass = Class.forName("com.hello.myproject.MAINACTIVITY");
Intent myintent = new Intent(Menu.this,myclass );
startActivity(myintent);
```

you must declare this Activity in manifest file with `intent-filter`

```
<activity
    android:name="com.hello.myproject.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.hello.myproject.MAINACTIVITY" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

### OR

As every on suggested, you can just use class name.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

### Update :

As you want to open different different Activities on List Item Click, here how you can do.. I am not sure but it should work.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Class myclass = Class.forName("com.hello.myproject." + classes[position]);
    Intent myintent = new Intent(Menu.this,myclass );
    startActivity(myintent);
}
```

Happy Coding...

Comment: Thankyou it worked when I put the above code inside a try block. I just learned to create a listactivity using values in string I have listed above. But the first value as you see MainActivity is an existing class but nothing happens when I click on it in the list. I stored all values of position inside a string. How can I move to another class listed inside I a String when I click on the list? Hope you understood the question

Comment: Hi, I had already done this but nothing happens when I click on an item which has a classname ie when I click on MainActivity nothing happens. and I have included them in the manifest file and the classname is same

Comment: ok now change `String []classes={"MainActivity","example1","example2","example3","example4","example5","example6"};` with `String []classes={"MAINACTIVITY","MENU","TEXTPLAY","example3","example4","example5","example6"};`

Comment: Can you please suggest me an alternative? I'm kinda stuck at this for hours now and cannot move on unless I get a solution.

Comment: HI refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/user/thenewboston) tutorial.. its exactly you want.. if you are learning Android this channel is best for you

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the name of `.class` where you want to go. Use like this:

```
Intent myintent=new Intent(Menu.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Intent myintent=new Intent(Menu.this, MainActivity.class);
```

OR

```
    Class myclass=Class.forName("MainActivity");
Intent myintent=new Intent(Menu.this, myclass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Define "MainActivity" inside Manifest xml file and the call like this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

hope it will work for you.